# Using Flask-Social with Oauth Provider(s) Only, No Local Registration/Login Forms

Tags: python, flask, facebook-oauth, flask-security

Is it possible to use Flask-Social and Flask-Security if I only want to use Facebook Login, for example, for user registration and login, i.e. no local registration/login forms?

I looked through the Flask-Social example application and documentation but couldn't tell if this is possible. In the example application, users cannot login with Facebook unless they've previously registered. After registering with the example application, they can associate their Facebook account with their local account.

When I tried to call social.facebook.get_connection() I got an `AttributeError 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'id'` because there's no `current_user`, which is defined by flask-security after registration/login.

Comment: @theva
you need to write the code like above in your project. please see https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-social-example/blob/master/app/__init__.py#L51 you will know where to place the code.
BTW,the above code have to change "db.commit()" to "ds.commit()"

Answer (score 5):

This is doable without too much extra work using the `@login_failed.connect_via` decorator. With `app` as your instance of a Flask app, it would look like

```
@login_failed.connect_via(app):
def on_login_failed(sender, provider, oauth_response):
    connection_values = get_connection_values_from_oauth_response(provider, oauth_response)
    ds = current_app.security.datastore
    user = ds.create_user( ... ) #fill in relevant stuff here
    ds.commit()
    connection_values['user_id'] = user.id
    connect_handler(connection_values, provider)
    login_user(user)
    db.commit()
    return render_template('success.html')
```

As for filling in the relevant stuff for creating the user, I just create a random string for the password, and haven't had issues leaving the email null. I also just included the exact same answer on the [Flask-Social github page](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-social/issues/27).

Comment: I know this is an old post but I can't find any docs for the @login_failed.connect_via decorator... Is this a part of Flask-social or Flask-security or something else?

Comment: @theva it's a signal that get's fired here: https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-social/blob/develop/flask_social/views.py#L192